# Is it possible to map a folder to library and vice versa?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, network-drive

We have 2 requirements (both are independent):

1. There is a doc library. We need to map it to a network path.
2. This is a doc library. We need to view it in the windows explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To map drive to a sharepoint site :

Windows

```
From the Start menu, right-click Computer or My Computer
In the Drives list, tap or click a drive letter. You may choose any available letter.
In the Folder or Path box, enter \\collaborate.uchicago.edu@SSL\<path to your site
For example if the URL of your site is https://collaborate.uchicago.edu/depts/ITS/team you would enter \\collaborate.uchicago.edu\depts\its\team
To connect every time you sign into your computer, select the Reconnect at sign-in check box.
If you do not log onto your computer with the same username and password that you use to access the SharePoint site, select Connect using different credentials.
Tap or click Finish
If the Windows security windows appears enter your username and password. Your username will need to be entered as follows:
CNetID - adlocal\<username>
UCHAD ID - uchad\<username>
```

Mac OS X

```
In OS X, to map a drive to your SharePoint site, use the Microsoft Document Connection application included with Office 2011.

In the Toolbar, click Add Location and select Connect to a SharePoint Site?
In the "Address" field, enter the URL of your site and click Connect.
Enter your username and password and click Connect.
```

To view documents in explorer view:

```
Open the document or picture library
On the toolbar, click the Actions drop-down list and select Open with Windows Explorer to open Windows Explorer in a new window
```

For more details:

http://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/use-windows-explorer-with-sharepoint-libraries

Answer (score 1):

If you browse to the Doc Library in Internet Explorer, from the Ribbon, select Library >> "Open in Explorer". This will open the Library in Windows Explorer and provide you with a network Path. You should be able to map a new network location to the path.